# What is the difference between NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar and NSGregorianCalendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, nscalendar

I have developed an app which works alot with dates and also stores these as strings in core data using this method:

```
- (NSDate*) stringToDate{
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
   NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:self];

   return date;
```

}

Working with date/time is quite tricky  - just alone the time difference between the system and the locale time - anyway the above method should take care of that. (So I hope, since formatting a NSDate to a NSString returns the correct local time instead of looking at the NSDate variable in debugger which shows a 2 hours difference in my case)

There are also many calculations like this:

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];   <------

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit |NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:someDate];

    NSInteger now_hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger now_minute = [components minute];
    NSInteger yearx =  [components year];
    NSInteger monthx =  [components month];
    NSInteger dayx =  [components day];
```

where I need to set/change/create certain dates/times, do calculations and retrieve/store them in core data again as NSStrings.

My question is about using the appropriate calendar.

Should I always write:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; ?
```

or

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
```

and

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSRepublicOfChinaCalendar];
```

**esp. depending on whether the app is used in Europe/USA vs China?**

Comment: Quote from doc: `A Chinese calendar can be created, and you can do calendrical calculations with it, but you should not use it for formatting as the necessary underlying functionality is not working correctly yet.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `stringToDate` won't actually exactly work, see [QA1480](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/). Short version: the `NSDateFormatter` unfortunately has two, slightly contradictory, roles — decoding and encoding specific text formats and converting dates for display. Because the latter is locale related, it's the default. To ensure you get the former behaviour, you should explicitly set the `en_US_POSIX` locale, which is guaranteed exactly to honour your date string.

That being said, you seem to be a little confused about what an `NSDate` is. It's not an `NSString` or any other written representation of a date. It's an abstract record of an exact moment. It's therefore completely unrelated to the current calendar. The user's calendar and locale will affect how dates are printed, but it doesn't affect the dates themselves. Now is still now, however you write it. That's why when you apply a formatter to a date you get a correct local date, but if you just log a date to the console then you get something abstract and not necessarily in your local time zone. `NSDate` has no concept of time zones or of different calendars.

Core Data can store dates directly (ie, there's no need whatsoever for you to convert to an from strings manually any more than there is for numeric values) so I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at. But normal behaviour is to use `currentCalendar` when you want to display something for the user. That'll display according to their time zone and other settings.

As per the QA, for applying fixed date strings you should use a date formatter with an explicitly set locale and not think about the calendar at all.

Comment: I felt there was something tricky about this - but never expected it to be so "dangerous". The basic reasoning behind converting dates to strings was that I thought it would be easier to handle during app development since I can always see the "correct" date/time instead of the "strange" result I see when looking at a variable in the debugger. If I had known that formatting to string and back can cause these errors I would simply have used normal dates with core data. So now I will use en_US_POSIX, hopefully that ensures that it will work correctly. Thanks very much for pointing this out!

Comment: But will this then also work if I get the current date/time with [NSDate date] and then compare the hour & minute with the stored dates/time? Or will the stored dates/time be in US time (bec I used en_US_POSIX) while the local time is totally different?

Comment: Just as a final comment - if anyone creates the strings themselves and gets them back there will be no problem - no need to use en_US_POSIX. As long as the app only stores and uses dates and strings it created itself (of course without any changes in corresponding settings) everything will be OK in all the countries and calendar settings....